# What causes ActiveRecord breaking Postgres connection after forking?

Tags: activerecord, fork, ruby-on-rails-4.2, postgresql-9.4

I have a Rake task in a Rails 4.2 project that uses `fork`. My problem is that after the forked process has finished (i.e. after `Process.wait`) I get the following Postgres error when I try to access the database again:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
```

At first I suspected ActiveRecord to automatically close the connection once the forked process finishes. But after reading the code of AR's [`connection_pool.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb) it seems that forked processes should use their own connections:

> A connection was established in an ancestor process that must have 
>   subsequently forked. We can't reuse the connection, but we can copy
>   the specification and establish a new connection with it.

(from [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler#pool_for_owner`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L623-625))

Nevertheless, forking renders the connection useless.

I tried to prevent the forked process from accessing the database at all and verified that the old connections cannot be reused with the following code after forking:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.default_connection_handler = nil
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler = nil
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: maybe the answer here helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089875/fork-ruby-activerecord-and-file-descriptors-on-fork

Answer (score 1):

After the child processes finish their work you can re-establish a connection to the DB with `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`. Afterwards your Rake process should be able to access the DB as usual.